# Get all cookies when create more Profile in Chrome

Tags: rust

I want to get all file cookies in local, when create more Profile in Chrome.
Ex:
../Google/Chrome/User Data/
Default 
Profile 1
Profile 2
... 
My code:

```
    fn build_cookie_directory(base_dir: &std::path::PathBuf) -> Result<Vec<std::path::PathBuf>, ()> {
    
    let mut base_directories = vec![];
    let cookie_dirs = vec![
        base_dir.join(lc!("Profile 1")).join(lc!("Cookies")),
        base_dir.join(lc!("Profile 2")).join(lc!("Cookies")),
        base_dir.join(lc!("Default")).join(lc!("Cookies")),
        base_dir.join(lc!("Cookies")),
    ];
    for cookie_dir in cookie_dirs { 

        if cookie_dir.exists() == true {
            base_directories.push(cookie_dir);
          
        }
    }
     Ok(base_directories)
  
}
```

"cookie_dirs" is hard code, I want "cookie_dirs" is get all list folder name contains string "Profile" .

Comment: Your code only *references* the "Default" folder. If you want to get access from a "Profile 1" folder, you should use that folder instead. I don't understand what the question is here.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I want get all cookies for all folder profile, can use for loop ,because I just learned about RUST, I don't know how to do it

Comment: What do you expect this function *to do*?  It's named `build_cookie_directory` but it's just *getting* a cookie directory.  That is confusing.  If you want it to *get* multiple cookie directories rather than just one, then it will need to return something other than a single `PathBuf`: consider changing its signature so that it returns a collection (e.g. a `Vec<PathBuf>`) or an iterator (e.g. `impl Iterator<Item = PathBuf>`) and then adjust the body accordingly.

Comment: @eggyal thank you, i had fix code , i want get list folder name contains string "Profile", my code  "cookie_dirs" is hard code, i want change to dynamic.